# Maven archetype webapp 404

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

i want create simply web app like in java/maven new project-archetype webapp and after i create it and use command mvn tomcat7:run is http 404 eror, know why ?
if i use classic deploy war file on my manager is working , but if i want use 1.method via archetype webapp and tomcat7:run doesnt work.
I copy http://localhost:8080/servlety and paste web browser and doesnt work.

```
PS C:\Users\*******\IdeaProjects\untitled\servlety> mvn tomcat7:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< wynny.servlety:servlety >-----------------------
[INFO] Building servlety Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ servlety >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ servlety ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\untitled\servlety\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ servlety ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ servlety <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ servlety ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/servlety
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\untitled\servlety\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /servlety
jan 19, 2022 11:16:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
jan 19, 2022 11:16:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind <null>:8080
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:407)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:544)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:388)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:274)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:218)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:394)
        ... 35 more

jan 19, 2022 11:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind <null>:8080
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:407)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:544)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:388)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:274)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:218)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:394)
        ... 35 more

jan 19, 2022 11:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
jan 19, 2022 11:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Comment: This looks like the problem: `: Address already in use: bind` apart from that is there a special reason using a 7 years+ old plugin (tomcat?)?

Comment: i following videos where using tomcat7:run so this is reason,but if have tomcat9 so command must lookslike mvn tomcat9:run ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception stack trace(startup trace) shows that your tomcat did not started due to port 8080 already in use:

```
Address already in use: bind <null>:8080
```

Also try start your tomcat:

```
mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081
```